# iPad app converted as Universal app appears in iPhone new apps?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, updates, ios-universal-app

I have an iPad app in the App Store and I'm currently converting it to iPhone as an Universal app.
I'm wondering if this app will appear in the App Store as a new app for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be one app. Wich will be the same download as iPad and iPhone. Just update it.

Answer (score 0):

A universal app is a single app that is optimized for iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad devices. Providing a single binary that adapts to the current device offers the best user experience but, of course, involves extra work on your part. Because of the differences in device screen sizes, most of your window, view, and view controller code for iPad is likely to be very different from the code for iPhone and iPod touch. In addition, there are things you must do to ensure your app runs correctly on each device type.

Xcode provides built-in support for configuring universal apps. When you create a new project, you can select whether you want to create a device-specific project or a universal project. After you create your project, you can change the supported set of devices for your app target using the Summary pane. When changing from a single-device project to a universal project, you must fill in the information for the device type for which you are adding support.

For more detail [Refer This Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will appear as new App under iPhone. iTunes App Store, put your App on the new Apps for every update you published. Since this is universal, so it shall appear under both iPhone and iPad